# How to stop beeping noise from the unencrypt device screen

Tags: encryption, reboot, volume-control, titanium-backup, disk-encryption

I have encrypted my phone, and set it so that it reboots each night - this works fine, however after it reboots, it asks for my password to unencrypted the device - still fine, however after a bit, it starts to beep - is there any way I can set it such that it does NOT beep at me? (some morning I like to sleep in, and scheduling those is too much of a pain).

alternatively, is there an easy way to have titanium backup just shutdown the phone instead of rebooting?

or perhaps instead of beeping, just shutting itself back down if the correct password isn't entered in X amount of time?

Comment: How did you get it to beep?  Mine doesn't beep and this is bad because if I'm GPS logging I lose data because I don't realize the device has restarted.

Comment: @Michael it started as soon as I encrypted my phone (note 2, n7100), but it takes a few minutes to start beeping after a reboot

Comment: Ah ok...after a bit more experimentation I found that it does beep on mine too, but it's so soft (more like a quiet chirp) that unless I am in a quiet room (e.g. sleeping without a fan noise at night) it doesn't really get my attention.